# how to get input from text area field

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

How do I get input from text area field using C# in ASP.NET? I have searched over the Internet but couldn't find anything. I am new to this field so please help.

Answer (score 8):

```
<textarea id="TextArea1" cols="20" rows="2" runat="server"></textarea>
```

specify the runat=server, and then, you can access it on the server-side. You can access text through `TextArea1.innerText` or `TextArea1.innerHtml`

```
String s = TextArea1.innerText;
```

Comment: sorry but it is not recognizing the id "TextArea1"

Comment: did you put runat=server in the declaration?